# Which instrument is this?

Tags: wind, instrument

Could anybody please help me to identify an instrument?
I guess it is some kind of reed or wind, like an harmonica or mouth organ but the sound is more nasal.

In the following video it can be heard at 1:03 and 1:14, unfortunately it only plays very short phrases and is mixed a bit into the back.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like harmonica or melodica..

Comment: I'm getting an error message. "This video contains content from Victor Entertainment, Inc... It is not available in your country" when I try to play it. Any chance you could find another source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's just a harmonica. Stevie Wonder style.

Go to 1:37 in this video.

Hope I'm right haha